# How to use gcc 4.9 when it's installed in same directory as newer gcc

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I've got installed both gcc 5 and gcc 4.9 in same directory (`/usr/bin`). Using `nvcc` with `--compiler-bindir` is impossible since both `gcc`s are in same directory.

I need to run command `nvcc --compiler-bindir /path/with/older/gcc/directory`. Is it possible to do that when both gccs are in same dir?

Comment: gcc-4.9 --version
gcc-4.9 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-5ubuntu1) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


LOL, I didn't think that it is already installed.

Comment: OK I have new question. I would like to set to nvcc compiler path (it needs directory where compiler is installed) 
but I have both gcc-4.9 and gcc-5 installed in /usr/bin ... which means that I can't specify path to gcc 4.9

Answer (score 4):

> I assume `nvcc` is the nVidia CUDA compiler, which is what this answer is based on, but since you don't provide that information, that's a guess...

---

The following is a snippet from the CUDA toolkit docs (at http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/):

> On all platforms, the default host compiler executable (`gcc` and `g++` on Linux, `clang` and `clang++` on Mac OS X, and `cl.exe` on Windows) found in the current execution search path will be used, unless specified otherwise with appropriate options (see File and Path Specifications). - See more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#sthash.Tphx1Ttz.dpuf

Based on this, you may be able to technically 'force' a `gcc` and `g++` version to be made available temporarily by the methodology in my now-deleted answer...

---

There's a reason that `update-alternatives` exists - it's designed to 'symlink' `gcc` and similar to the *actual* executable names.  In reality, `/usr/bin/gcc-4.9` is actually the gcc 4.9 compiler executable, and `gcc` just symlinks to `/etc/alternatives/gcc` which in turn is a symlink to the real gcc executable

In my 14.04 environment this is shown here:

```
% file /usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/gcc' 
% file /etc/alternatives/gcc
/etc/alternatives/gcc: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.8'
```

I actually have many versions of GCC on here, from 4.6 to 4.9, but this applies to other versions too.

To change the alternative one temporarily, you can do it with this command: `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`

This is what it shows on my system, with a blinky cursor at the end:

```
% sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
There are 4 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gcc-4.8   60        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gcc-4.6   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gcc-4.7   50        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/gcc-4.8   60        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/gcc-4.9   40        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I manually redid the priorities, but you can see that I can manually select which compiler I want to use in the interim.  Therefore, you can temporarily change this, and then switch it to the `gcc` you want, and then switch it back when finished.

This should, then, permit you to temporarily use one compiler by `gcc` or `g++` invocation, rather than having to specify a compiler directory.

***Note that this will likely need to also be done for `g++` as well - especially given the snippet from the docs above.***  So, use `g++` instead of `gcc` for changing `g++`'s 'version to use'.

The problem is, I don't see any easier way than this, in this case.  So every time you go in and change the compiler in this manner, to get it back to the default you need to run the `update-alternatives` commands again to re-set it back to what it was.

---

Alternatively, you could try and use the solution posed by [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver), which points to another potential solution (over on the Unix & Linux site):

> The method I've seen [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241127/65304) is to symlink the desired gcc-x.y version to /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc (and likewise for g++-x.y) - is this no longer valid?

Not sure if this approach will work, based on the documentation snippet I read, but it may work since that answer's been out there a while.

Comment: The method I've seen [elsewhere](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241127/65304) is to symlink the desired `gcc-x.y` version to `/usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc` (and likewise for `g++-x.y`) - is this no longer valid?

Comment: @steeldriver Unsure, but that's also a potential option.  However, that path you've identified isn't in the default search `$PATH` so it might be 'missed' as a result (this is why I stated the longer, `update-alternatives` approach)